# ¿Cómo dejar ver el contenido de un sitio únicamente desde el iframe en otro sitio con .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo un sitio web publico en wordpress, llamado AAA. Quiero poner mi sitio web en un iframe de otro sitio web (no wordpress) llamado BBB. Quiero que solamente se pueda acceder a AAA mediante el iframe en BBB y una vez iniciada la sesión en BBB.

Creo que eso se podría lograr con .htaccess `%{REMOTE_ADDR}`  pero no sé cómo hacerlo para que no sea posible a acceder a AAA mediante ningún enlace sino solamente si se inicia la sesión en BBB, pero sin tener ningún tipo de validación de sesión en AAA. ¿Es eso posible?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Order deny, allow
Deny from All
Allow from tuip

Comment: @JackNavaRow podrias incluir tu solucion en mi codigo en una respuesta y explicarlo un poco ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar las siguiente linea

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from All 
Allow from ip
```

con estos le estas diciendo a apache que impida todos los accesos excepto **`ip`**, tu vritual quedaria mas o menos de esta forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from All 
    Allow from ip
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Eso no responde 100% a mi pregunta, ya que no he mencionado que todos los usuarios serían del mismo IP, pero resuelve mi duda, porque efectivamente todos los usuarios serán del mismo IP, por eso marco como respuesta válida. Gracias ! :)